# How to group checkboxes with different names together

Tags: html

I have a couple of checkbox that I would like to make only one of them clickable. I have tried different solutions on stack overflow. I also changes changed the input type to radio and I have used the following code but still its not working:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
        // When any radio button on the page is selected,
        // then deselect all other radio buttons.
        $('input[type=radio]:checked').not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
});​
```

My Code is as follows:

```
 <div id="options-content5" class="collapse">
                                <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                    <input id="checkbox15" type="checkbox" name="last24">
                                    <label for="checkbox15">
                                        Last 24 Hours
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                    <input id="checkbox16" type="checkbox" name="last3Days">
                                    <label for="checkbox16">
                                        Last 3 days
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
                                    <input id="checkbox17" type="checkbox" name="last7Days">
                                    <label for="checkbox17">
                                        Last 7 days
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Can I ask why the `name` has to be different? It seems like a lot of extra work to recreate radio button functionality when you have HTML available out of the box - you should have a very good reason for doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make only one of a set of checkboxes clickable, use radio buttons with the same name. This will be much better for usability and accessibility. Here's an article from the Nielsen Norman Group about how to choose between checkboxes and radio buttons and why it matters. https://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/

I'd recommend using the values in place of your names to differentiate.

```html
<div id="options-content5" class="collapse">
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
    <input id="checkbox15" type="radio" name="lastTimeFrame" value="last24">
    <label for="checkbox15">Last 24 Hours</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
    <input id="checkbox16" type="radio" name="lastTimeFrame" value="last3Days">
    <label for="checkbox16">Last 3 days</label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox checkbox-theme checkbox-circle">
    <input id="checkbox17" type="radio" name="lastTimeFrame" value="last7Days">
    <label for="checkbox17">Last 7 days</label>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: but how possible when I sent back the name to controller to know which click-box has been clicked

Comment: I don't know what your code looks like, but you can read `event.target.value` or look up all radio buttons and check which one is checked.